# How to create a default branch in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am not able to push code to GitLab for the first time.

I have created a Gitlab project on the web interface.
I have created an ASP MVC project.
I did "`git init`" in that directory.
I added remote `origin`.
I added and committed the changes and then, when I want to push the changes to remote I get the following error:

```
remote: A default branch (e.g. master) does not yet exist for
...
remote: Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch:
...
error: failed to push some refs to
```

So I want to know if I can create a branch with the role `Developer`?
If yes how to create a default branch?
If no, what should my next steps be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that Gitlab did not create the "protected branch" settings, because the developer in question does not have that privilege. Why Gitlab allowed the creation of the repo in the first place seems backwards, but that's just, like, ah, my opinion, man.

So there's 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Elevate the developer-in-question's privileges to "Maintainer", or
2. Another maintainer can go into the repository's "Settings" -> "Repository", and under "Protected Branches", and create an entry for `main` (or whatever you want the default branch to be), and set it up so the user who created the repo can also push to main. The result will look like this:
   [image: protected branch settings]
   Gitlab will show the `main` branch as "deleted" because it doesn't yet exist, but the developer will now be able to push their code.

Answer (score 18):

This is followed by [issue 54155](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/54155)

> It seems as though 'developer' should not be able to create projects if it does not have permission to then populate that project without asking an admin to intervene.
>
> I don't understand, why I have enough permissions to create a project, but not to make it ready enough so I can push into it, and need to use another persons time in my organization to get ready to work.
>
> IMHO it would be logical to either allow users with status developer to create a project in a way that it's ready to push code to - or just don't let developers create a project and tell them they have to ask a maintainer or owner.

[Issue 51688](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/51688) mentions:

> Then I have to login with gitlab admin admin...Aggregate access to user test to test6.git as a `dev` or `maintainer`... and finally I can make push... But if user `test` creates another repo, I have to repeat all these steps again....
>
> Maintainer can create new branch. Please use maintainer account to push the new project.
>
> But it doesn't make sense that a user has permissions to create empty repositories but not initialize a default branch or push to their newly created repository.